# Adding a text only panel to base graphics layout

Tags: r, graphics

3 plots arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns

```
 attach(mtcars)
 par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
 plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
 boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
```

But how do I create a panel with just text and then add it to the fourth position in the grid. Apologies. I see now that like many quesioners I was asking you to read my mind or intuit from my code that I expected the text to be arranged left-justified in a grid of locations in the blank space.

(For some reason this seemed perfectly reasonable to ask but it was deleted, despite no close votes or nomination for duplicates offered. I'll put in what I had cobbled together, as an answer but there might be more elegant solutions. I did look at the titles for nominations of similar questions, but didn't find any that matched this problem.)

```
plot(1:100, 1:100, axes=FALSE, ylab="", xlab="", type="n")
text( rep(c(1,50), each=10), rep( seq(1, 100, by=10),2), labels=letters[1:20])
```

I've wondered after the fact whether a fine grained grid was the right way to do it. Perhaps a coarser grid with just the right number of rows and columns and using left justified text would be more table-like. The gridExtra package with baptiste's tableGrob might also be a productive direction.

An alternate text argument to "plot" might be:

```
txt <- structure(c("am", "carb", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "gear", "hp", 
                   "mpg", "qsec", "vs", "wt", "this"), .Dim = 3:4)


> txt
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "am"   "disp" "hp"   "vs"  
[2,] "carb" "drat" "mpg"  "wt"  
[3,] "cyl"  "gear" "qsec" "this"
```

Comment: isn't plot.new() good for this?

Comment: Well, it's certainly better than my hacking with `plot.default` for changing focus, but I thought sticking a table in that space was a prototypical text-oriented task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example,

```
library(gplots)
textplot(txt)
```

[image]

There's also `addtable2plot` in `plotrix`, and an alternative solution would be to mix base and grid graphics with the gridBase package, and place a `tableGrob` from the `gridExtra` package.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd throw in my two cents here. I see two simple ways to do this (granted neither shows row and column indices, as currently configured). Both use `text` as you've proposed, but work to layout things in the coarser grid you discuss but don't show. For left-alignment in both the key argument is `pos`.

#### Option 1 (uses linebreaks to create the grid)

```
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
txt <- structure(c("am", "carb", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "gear", "hp", 
                   "mpg", "qsec", "vs", "wt", "this"), .Dim = 3:4)

plot.new()
sapply(1:4, function(i) text(i/4, .5, paste(txt[,i],collapse='\n'), pos=4))
```

[image]

#### Option 2 (uses text vectorization to create the grid)

```
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
txt <- structure(c("am", "carb", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "gear", "hp", 
                   "mpg", "qsec", "vs", "wt", "this"), .Dim = 3:4)

plot.new()
sapply(1:4, function(i) text(i/4, (1:3)/3, rev(txt[,i]), pos=4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what text you want, but here's a "hello world":

```
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,"hello world",cex=6)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see that as a big improvement over what I had offered. Mine had two columns of ten positions each. But you have improved my knowledge of the coordinate system of an un-'plot'-ed graphics region.  Was looking for something more table-like.

Comment: Oh I see.  So it's not just getting a panel with text, you want a convenient way to be able to make tables and arrange the text nicely.  I'm afraid this is where my expertise in this area ends...